# Google CSP Evaluator and style-src 'unsafe-inline'

Tags: web-application, content-security-policy, css

Google provides a CSP evaluator to validate if a given content-security policy is well set up ([github](https://github.com/google/csp-evaluator), [validator](https://csp-evaluator.withgoogle.com/)). However, if one uses `'unsafe-inline'` in the `style-src` directive this is reported as 'all good' (See image below).

Does this not (mostly) defeat the purpose of defining a style source? As far as I understand an attacker would be able to inject CSS. Not as big of an issue as JavaScript execution, but I would not report it with a green checkmark. What am I missing here?

[image: Results from the CSP evaluator.]

Comment: My guess is it just doesn't consider styles to be a high-risk issue compared to XSS. It doesn't even complain if you omit style-src and default-src entirely as long as script-src is configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you this should not be a green checkmark. A coding mistake that would allow for style injection could still be abused for website defacing and possibly phishing attacks. I expect you could count this as a medium finding.

Looking at the repository, there are more issues that should get some attention, but I think it is not a priority of Google at this time.